# How can I sort by a nested JSONB attribute in sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to sort a sequelize query by a nested attribute of a JSONB object.

I have a model like that:

```
sequelize.define('product', {
    available: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN },
    price: { type: Sequelize.JSONB },
    ...
}
```

where price is kind of this:

```
price = {
    EUR: 1.2,
    CHF: 1.3,
}
```

I want to sort a findAll query by price.EUR. I hoped that this works:

```
product.findAll({ where: { available: true }, order: [['price.EUR', 'ASC']] }
```

But I get an unsorted array.

The underlying DB is postgres.

A solution is to sort the result programmatically in javascript (array._prototype.sort()). But I wonder if it is possible with a sequelize query.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
roduct.findAll({ where: { available: true }, order: [[sequelize.literal('price->>\'EUR\''), 'ASC']] }
```